# Paypal Custom amount type on Express

Tags: paypal

I am integrating Express Checkout for a restaurant website, and would like to show "Tip" apart from taxes and subtotal on the Paypal review page order details. Like:

[Individual item details]

..

Item Total     $20

Taxes          $2

*Tip            $4*

**Total          $26**

I have referred api here : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

and here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/

and notice this parameter `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM`, but it only accepts "256 single-byte alphanumeric characters." 
How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM is associated with a unique code which will be assigned to each product which you set using paypal express checkout API.

For item total use

> PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMAMT and PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT

For Taxes use

> PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TAXAMT

For TIP use

> PAYMENTREQUEST_n_HANDLINGAMT

Answer (score 1):

The PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM parameter is something for developers to store custom data. It won't be shown anywhere.

About the tip, I'm afraid the only options is to add it as another an item of your order.